# Forcing Blender to measure ONLY in inches (not feet)

Tags: interface

I have Blender set to Imperial but I want to work **ONLY** in inches. So for example, 13 inches to show as 13" and NOT 1.1'  and 72" to show as 72" and NOT 6'

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you check the separate units check box that should give you what you at least the thing displayed in feet and inches(rather than decimal notation).  But I don't know if it possible to have it only show in inches as noted in your example.

[image]

Comment: That's better... I guess.. Thanks. But still it would REALLY be best if I could get it to show ONLY inches.  Is there an addon out there that might do it? I searched a bit but didn't find one.